# Designer preview not the same when I run my program

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qt-designer

I have a problem because when I execute the preview in Qt Designer I see like this:
[image: this]. But when I execute my program in pycharm I see like this:
[image: this].

The distribution that I have I Qt Designer is this:
[image: this].

The code of the window.py:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1500, 750)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QSize(1500, 5000))
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(1080, 750))
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.cabecera_principal = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.cabecera_principal.setObjectName(u"cabecera_principal")
        self.cabecera_principal.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 70))
        self.cabecera_principal.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(55, 0, 179);\n"
"")
        self.cabecera_principal.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.cabecera_principal.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.cabecera_principal)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.cabecera_contenedor = QFrame(self.cabecera_principal)
        self.cabecera_contenedor.setObjectName(u"cabecera_contenedor")
        self.cabecera_contenedor.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 0))
        self.cabecera_contenedor.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(55, 0, 179);")
        self.cabecera_contenedor.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.cabecera_contenedor.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QHBoxLayout(self.cabecera_contenedor)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.btns_izqda = QFrame(self.cabecera_contenedor)
        self.btns_izqda.setObjectName(u"btns_izqda")
        self.btns_izqda.setMinimumSize(QSize(70, 0))
        self.btns_izqda.setMaximumSize(QSize(50, 16777215))
        self.btns_izqda.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton{\n"
"   border-radius:5px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"   \n"
"   background-color: rgb(3, 218, 197);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.btns_izqda.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.btns_izqda.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Plain)
        self.btns_izqda.setLineWidth(1)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QHBoxLayout(self.btns_izqda)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 2, 0)
        self.btn_menu = QPushButton(self.btns_izqda)
        self.btn_menu.setObjectName(u"btn_menu")
        self.btn_menu.setMinimumSize(QSize(70, 70))
        self.btn_menu.setMaximumSize(QSize(70, 16777215))
        self.btn_menu.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(u"iconos/btn_menu.svg", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_menu.setIcon(icon)
        self.btn_menu.setIconSize(QSize(50, 50))

        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_menu)


        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.btns_izqda)

        self.espacio_titulo = QFrame(self.cabecera_contenedor)
        self.espacio_titulo.setObjectName(u"espacio_titulo")
        self.espacio_titulo.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.espacio_titulo.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.espacio_titulo.setLineWidth(0)

        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.espacio_titulo)


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.cabecera_contenedor)

        self.btns_nav_ventana = QFrame(self.cabecera_principal)
        self.btns_nav_ventana.setObjectName(u"btns_nav_ventana")
        self.btns_nav_ventana.setMaximumSize(QSize(150, 16777215))
        self.btns_nav_ventana.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.btns_nav_ventana.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton{\n"
"   border-radius:5px;\n"
"}\n"
"/* Para poder ver en otro color cuando estamos encima*/\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"   \n"
"   background-color: rgb(3, 218, 197);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.btns_nav_ventana.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.btns_nav_ventana.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QHBoxLayout(self.btns_nav_ventana)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_3")
        self.btn_minimizar = QPushButton(self.btns_nav_ventana)
        self.btn_minimizar.setObjectName(u"btn_minimizar")
        self.btn_minimizar.setMaximumSize(QSize(30, 30))
        self.btn_minimizar.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        icon1 = QIcon()
        icon1.addFile(u"iconos/ventana/icn_minimizar.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_minimizar.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btn_minimizar.setIconSize(QSize(29, 29))

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_minimizar)

        self.btn_maximizar = QPushButton(self.btns_nav_ventana)
        self.btn_maximizar.setObjectName(u"btn_maximizar")
        self.btn_maximizar.setMaximumSize(QSize(30, 30))
        self.btn_maximizar.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        icon2 = QIcon()
        icon2.addFile(u"iconos/ventana/icn_maximizar.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_maximizar.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btn_maximizar.setIconSize(QSize(29, 29))

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_maximizar)

        self.btn_cerrar = QPushButton(self.btns_nav_ventana)
        self.btn_cerrar.setObjectName(u"btn_cerrar")
        self.btn_cerrar.setMaximumSize(QSize(40, 30))
        self.btn_cerrar.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        icon3 = QIcon()
        icon3.addFile(u"iconos/ventana/icn_close.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_cerrar.setIcon(icon3)
        self.btn_cerrar.setIconSize(QSize(29, 29))

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_cerrar)


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btns_nav_ventana)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.cabecera_principal)

        self.cuerpo_principal = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.cuerpo_principal.setObjectName(u"cuerpo_principal")
        self.cuerpo_principal.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(55, 0, 179);")
        self.cuerpo_principal.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.cuerpo_principal.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.cuerpo_principal)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.menu_izquierda = QFrame(self.cuerpo_principal)
        self.menu_izquierda.setObjectName(u"menu_izquierda")
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.menu_izquierda.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.menu_izquierda.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.menu_izquierda.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 0))
        self.menu_izquierda.setMaximumSize(QSize(70, 16777215))
        self.menu_izquierda.setStyleSheet(u"QFrame{\n"
"   background-color: rgb(55, 0, 179);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"   \n"
"   border-radius:8px\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"   \n"
"   background-color: rgb(3, 218, 197);\n"
"}")
        self.menu_izquierda.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.menu_izquierda.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.menu_izquierda.setLineWidth(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QHBoxLayout(self.menu_izquierda)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 0, 0)
        self.btns_menu_arriba = QFrame(self.menu_izquierda)
        self.btns_menu_arriba.setObjectName(u"btns_menu_arriba")
        self.btns_menu_arriba.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.btns_menu_arriba.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.btn_home = QPushButton(self.btns_menu_arriba)
        self.btn_home.setObjectName(u"btn_home")
        self.btn_home.setGeometry(QRect(0, 10, 180, 61))
        self.btn_home.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.btn_home.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/logos/btn_home.svg);\n"
"   background-repeat:none;\n"
"   padding-left:25px;\n"
"\n"
"   font: 9pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"   color:white;")
        self.btn_home.setIconSize(QSize(24, 24))
        self.btn_home.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btn_home.setFlat(False)
        self.btn_entrenamiento = QPushButton(self.btns_menu_arriba)
        self.btn_entrenamiento.setObjectName(u"btn_entrenamiento")
        self.btn_entrenamiento.setGeometry(QRect(0, 90, 180, 61))
        sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_entrenamiento.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_entrenamiento.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
        self.btn_entrenamiento.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/logos/btn_entrenamiento.svg);\n"
"   background-repeat:none;\n"
"   padding-left:40px;\n"
"\n"
"   font: 9pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"   color:white;\n"
"")
        icon4 = QIcon()
        icon4.addFile(u"icons/menu/btn_entrenamiento.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_entrenamiento.setIcon(icon4)
        self.btn_entrenamiento.setIconSize(QSize(24, 24))
        self.btn_rendimiento = QPushButton(self.btns_menu_arriba)
        self.btn_rendimiento.setObjectName(u"btn_rendimiento")
        self.btn_rendimiento.setGeometry(QRect(0, 170, 180, 51))
        self.btn_rendimiento.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/logos/btn_rendimiento.svg);\n"
"   background-repeat:none;\n"
"   padding-left:40px;\n"
"\n"
"   font: 9pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"   color:white;")
        icon5 = QIcon()
        icon5.addFile(u"icons/menu/btn_rendimiento.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_rendimiento.setIcon(icon5)
        self.btn_rendimiento.setIconSize(QSize(24, 24))
        self.btn_jugadores = QPushButton(self.btns_menu_arriba)
        self.btn_jugadores.setObjectName(u"btn_jugadores")
        self.btn_jugadores.setGeometry(QRect(0, 250, 180, 51))
        self.btn_jugadores.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/logos/btn_jugadores.svg);\n"
"background-repeat:none;\n"
"padding-left:45px;\n"
"\n"
"   font: 9pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"   color:white;")
        icon6 = QIcon()
        icon6.addFile(u"icons/menu/btn_jugadores.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_jugadores.setIcon(icon6)
        self.btn_jugadores.setIconSize(QSize(24, 24))
        self.btn_ejercicios = QPushButton(self.btns_menu_arriba)
        self.btn_ejercicios.setObjectName(u"btn_ejercicios")
        self.btn_ejercicios.setGeometry(QRect(0, 340, 180, 61))
        self.btn_ejercicios.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/logos/btn_ejercicios.svg);\n"
"background-repeat:none;\n"
"padding-left:45px;\n"
"\n"
"font: 9pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        icon7 = QIcon()
        icon7.addFile(u"icons/menu/btn_ejercicio.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_ejercicios.setIcon(icon7)
        self.btn_ejercicios.setIconSize(QSize(24, 24))
        self.btn_opciones = QPushButton(self.btns_menu_arriba)
        self.btn_opciones.setObjectName(u"btn_opciones")
        self.btn_opciones.setGeometry(QRect(0, 590, 180, 51))
        self.btn_opciones.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/logos/btn_opciones.svg);\n"
"   background-repeat:none;\n"
"   padding-left:45px;\n"
"\n"
"   font: 9pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"   color:white;\n"
"")
        icon8 = QIcon()
        icon8.addFile(u"icons/menu/btn_opciones.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_opciones.setIcon(icon8)
        self.btn_opciones.setIconSize(QSize(24, 24))

        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.btns_menu_arriba)


        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.menu_izquierda)

        self.contenido_principal = QFrame(self.cuerpo_principal)
        self.contenido_principal.setObjectName(u"contenido_principal")
        self.contenido_principal.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"")
        self.contenido_principal.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.contenido_principal.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.pila_de_paginas = QStackedWidget(self.contenido_principal)
        self.pila_de_paginas.setObjectName(u"pila_de_paginas")
        self.pila_de_paginas.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1431, 651))
        self.pg_inicio = QWidget()
        self.pg_inicio.setObjectName(u"pg_inicio")
        self.pila_de_paginas.addWidget(self.pg_inicio)
        self.pg_entreno = QWidget()
        self.pg_entreno.setObjectName(u"pg_entreno")
        self.pila_de_paginas.addWidget(self.pg_entreno)
        self.pg_rendimiento = QWidget()
        self.pg_rendimiento.setObjectName(u"pg_rendimiento")
        self.pila_de_paginas.addWidget(self.pg_rendimiento)
        self.pg_jugadores = QWidget()
        self.pg_jugadores.setObjectName(u"pg_jugadores")
        self.lbl_jgds_incluidos = QLabel(self.pg_jugadores)
        self.lbl_jgds_incluidos.setObjectName(u"lbl_jgds_incluidos")
        self.lbl_jgds_incluidos.setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 631, 51))
        self.lbl_jgds_incluidos.setStyleSheet(u"font: 17pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"color: rgb(3, 218, 197);\n"
"background-color: rgb(55, 0, 179);")
        self.tabla_jgds = QTableWidget(self.pg_jugadores)
        if (self.tabla_jgds.columnCount() < 4):
            self.tabla_jgds.setColumnCount(4)
        __qtablewidgetitem = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tabla_jgds.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem)
        __qtablewidgetitem1 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tabla_jgds.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem1)
        __qtablewidgetitem2 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tabla_jgds.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, __qtablewidgetitem2)
        __qtablewidgetitem3 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tabla_jgds.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, __qtablewidgetitem3)
        if (self.tabla_jgds.rowCount() < 2):
            self.tabla_jgds.setRowCount(2)
        __qtablewidgetitem4 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tabla_jgds.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem4)
        __qtablewidgetitem5 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tabla_jgds.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem5)
        self.tabla_jgds.setObjectName(u"tabla_jgds")
        self.tabla_jgds.setGeometry(QRect(20, 80, 631, 192))
        self.btn_actualizar_jugadores = QPushButton(self.pg_jugadores)
        self.btn_actualizar_jugadores.setObjectName(u"btn_actualizar_jugadores")
        self.btn_actualizar_jugadores.setGeometry(QRect(920, 240, 171, 23))
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar = QLabel(self.pg_jugadores)
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar.setObjectName(u"lbl_jdgs_a_borrar")
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar.setGeometry(QRect(690, 30, 591, 31))
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar.setStyleSheet(u"font: 13pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"color: rgb(3, 218, 197);")
        self.label = QLabel(self.pg_jugadores)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(690, 90, 131, 31))
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.pg_jugadores)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(690, 160, 141, 31))
        self.btn_borrar_jugador = QPushButton(self.pg_jugadores)
        self.btn_borrar_jugador.setObjectName(u"btn_borrar_jugador")
        self.btn_borrar_jugador.setGeometry(QRect(690, 240, 171, 23))
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar_2 = QLabel(self.pg_jugadores)
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar_2.setObjectName(u"lbl_jdgs_a_borrar_2")
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar_2.setGeometry(QRect(70, 310, 1131, 51))
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar_2.setStyleSheet(u"font: 17pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"color: rgb(3, 218, 197);")
        self.txt_numero_jugador_borrar = QLineEdit(self.pg_jugadores)
        self.txt_numero_jugador_borrar.setObjectName(u"txt_numero_jugador_borrar")
        self.txt_numero_jugador_borrar.setGeometry(QRect(870, 100, 113, 20))
        self.txt_nombre_jugador_borrar = QLineEdit(self.pg_jugadores)
        self.txt_nombre_jugador_borrar.setObjectName(u"txt_nombre_jugador_borrar")
        self.txt_nombre_jugador_borrar.setGeometry(QRect(870, 160, 113, 20))
        self.pila_de_paginas.addWidget(self.pg_jugadores)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.contenido_principal)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.cuerpo_principal)

        self.pie_principal = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.pie_principal.setObjectName(u"pie_principal")
        self.pie_principal.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.pie_principal.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(98, 0, 238);")
        self.pie_principal.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.pie_principal.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pie_principal)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        self.pila_de_paginas.setCurrentIndex(3)


        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.btn_menu.setText("")
        self.btn_minimizar.setText("")
        self.btn_maximizar.setText("")
        self.btn_cerrar.setText("")
        self.btn_home.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"     RESUMEN", None))
        self.btn_entrenamiento.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"ENTRENO", None))
        self.btn_rendimiento.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"        RENDIMIENTO", None))
        self.btn_jugadores.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"  JUGADORES", None))
        self.btn_ejercicios.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"EJERCICIOS", None))
        self.btn_opciones.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u" OPCIONES", None))
        self.lbl_jgds_incluidos.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"JUGADORES QUE EST\u00c1N DISPONIBLES", None))
        ___qtablewidgetitem = self.tabla_jgds.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Numero", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem1 = self.tabla_jgds.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Nombre", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem2 = self.tabla_jgds.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        ___qtablewidgetitem2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Apellidos", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem3 = self.tabla_jgds.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        ___qtablewidgetitem3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Posicion", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem4 = self.tabla_jgds.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem5 = self.tabla_jgds.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem5.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None));
        self.btn_actualizar_jugadores.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Actualizar Tabla", None))
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"SI QUIERES BORRAR ALGUN JUGADOR DE ESTA LISTA, INDICA LOS SIGUIENTES DATOS :", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"NUMERO DE JUGADOR ", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"NOMBRE DEL JUGADOR", None))
        self.btn_borrar_jugador.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Borrar Jugador", None))
        self.lbl_jdgs_a_borrar_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"SI QUIERES A\u00d1ADIR ALGUN JUGADOR A LA LISTA, INDICA LOS SIGUIENTES DATOS :", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Does anyone know what I have to do to see like in the preview of QT Designer?
I have tried to change the size of the Windows but it is not that.

Comment: From what I can see, you're probably not using [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html), but it's hard to know that since you posted the wrong code: what you provided is the "logic" part of your program, we need the UI. If you still have the ui file created in Designer (not "Desginer"), you can edit your post, and embed that one instead of the current which is completely unnecessary for this issue.

Comment: okey, i have edited the post. Sorry about that, you are right !

Comment: Actually, as said, the `ui` file created with Designer is more useful than the pyuic created file. You still have that, don't you?

Comment: Sorry mate!! i didnt understand ! I tried to paste on post but its to long, what can i do ?

Comment: That is exactly what I was afraid of: a lot of widgets you're using are "floating" (they are not part of a layout, they are just put inside a parent at a specific position and with a specific size, which is usually considered bad practice, and the reason is exactly what you're seeing: widgets gets messed up). Read the link in my first comment, and ensure that **all** widgets are part of a layout (just check the icon on their parent in the object inspector of Designer, if it has a red "forbidden" icon, it means that there's no layout there).

Comment: Read that first link, learn how to use layouts, and then try to modify your current ui. And remember that there's also drag&drop.

Comment: i have tried using grid layout on the page that i am coding but i have the same problem.... When i use the preview it looks perfect but when i run the program the title of a label not appear as the preview. I can only see the half of the title. Do you have any idea why it´s ocurring that ?

Comment: Then you probably have set fixed/maximum size on some of the widgets.